# Theoretically, would two up-to-date windows systems be of a similar size?

Tags: windows, windows-update, operating-system

If on one computer the windows OS was installed two years ago, and on the other, say, just yesterday...
assuming both machines have the exact configuration hardware-wise. and that both machines are up to date with the windows-update feature. 
would the two C:\Windows folders be the same size on the two machines?

Edit:
My windows partition grew up so big it can barely fit anymore. Within windows there is this "installer" folder that's huge in space. I was wondering, if I format the partition, reinstall windows 7, would that help, or would the windows folder be just as big after all the updates have been applied? –  Ted 20 hours ago   delete

Comment: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

No. All of the effects and remnants of the intermediate updates over the last two years would be on the older one, but not the newer one. The C:\Windows\Temp folder is one obvious example of differences.

However, if the OS was installed 2 years ago and then the computer was immediately turned off until yesterday, then possibly yes.

Answer (score 0):

No necessarily, it depends on if they also have the same features and roles. Why do you ask, what actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi, just edited my question